# Will windows 10 automatically detect my external tv/monitor?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display, windows-10

I have a windows 8, now 8.1 hp laptop with a damaged screen. I wanted to know if I upgraded or did a clean install to windows 10, would it automatically recognize my external monitor/tv. When I had 8 and upgraded to 8.1 it automatically recognized it. Will windows 10 do the same? I tried to install windows 10 yesterday and I couldnt tell if it was done installing because it wasnt on my external screen. I  noticed that the wifi light was on and the cap locks was able to be turned off and on so I thought it was done. So I then restarted the computer seeing how I wasnt able to see the screen and it powered back up on the external monitor saying it failed to install windows 10 and something about system.boot so i figured it was because I restarted the computer. It went back to the 8.1 version.  Maybe if I waited longer it would've kicked on the external screen? What should I do? I posted this before but somehow it was deleted..

Comment: How is the monitor connected?

Comment: It's connected by an HDMI cord

Comment: It should be detected as monitors don't require drivers, but whether or not it will automatically output to the monitor is another issue. Usually you would have to press some key combination to switch the display.

Comment: I now have it remoted where I can see everything that I do on the laptop on my tablet so if I install it now, would I be able to see it on tablet just in case it doesnt show on external monitor.

Comment: Are you using something like TeamViewer? During the installation process that may not work as it restarts multiple times and probably would not start your remote program.

Comment: I'm using the LogMeIn app

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I doubt that will be running while Windows 10 installs itself and modifies your system. Worth a shot though, I guess.

Comment: So ive started the installation it restarted i believe. Screen is not on but the wifi light on keyboard is blue and im able to turn on caps

Comment: It worked, it installed then i waited a while. I almost gave up so i turned  the monitor off and when i turned it back on it was on. Thankyou for your help

Comment: Since you solved the problem, it would be helpful to others if you wrote up the solution as an answer. (Answering your own questions is encouraged, if you know the answer.)

Answer (score -1):

There's not really an answer to this question. It automatically detected the external monitor after the Installation was done and the external monitor was plugged back up and turned on. Patience is the key!